# what's the "Object" really mean in Object constructor?

Tags: javascript

I'm from Java/C# background, the traditional OOP language. it is really hard for me understand javascript world. Below is an example and my questions:

```
var o = new Object(123);
```

Q1- is the `Object` in `new Object()` actually a function like

```
function Object() {
   ...
}
```

Q2- if the answer to question 1 is yes then I'm confused with `Object.prototype`, that means `prototype` is a property for object function, so how can a function has its property? so how can we add a new property in a function like

```
function Object() {
   ...
   prototype: ...          //obviously this is not the right syntax 
}
```

can any body provides me a skeleton code for this?

Q3- what I check `console.log(typeof Object)`, the output is "function", since an function is also an object, so why the output is not "object"

Comment: Please read the following resource: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/this-object-prototypes/README.md

Comment: I would like to recommend you to read the basics. Please see this link regarding `Object` https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp. I think all questions are answered here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `Object` is a function in `new Object(123)`.

Older version like [**ES5**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) class is written like this pattern

```
function MyClass () {
    // .....
}
```

But in ES6 the original class keyword can be used like Java/C#

```
class MyClass 
{
    constructor() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In JavaScript the [**prototype**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) is used to inherit the class properties and this concept for the older version of ES6

According to  MDN documentation the [**Object.Prototype**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) is

> Nearly all objects in JavaScript are instances of Object; a typical object inherits properties (including methods) from Object.prototype, although these properties may be shadowed (a.k.a. overridden). However, an Object may be deliberately created for which this is not true (e.g. by Object.create(null)), or it may be altered so that this is no longer true (e.g. with Object.setPrototypeOf).
>
> Changes to the Object prototype object are seen by all objects through prototype chaining, unless the properties and methods subject to those changes are overridden further along the prototype chain. This provides a very powerful although potentially dangerous mechanism to override or extend object behavior.

**Prototype Example:**

Consider the following `Employee` class

```
function Employee() 
{
    this.organization = 'xyz';
}
```

If you want to add a function `details` property to that `Employee` class, then you can use `prototype`. Example:

```
Employee.prototype.details = function() 
{
    this.age = 26;
    this.designation = 'Software Engineer';
    // ....
}
```

Now, create the object of that `Employee` class

```
var emp = new Employee();
console.log(emp.organization, emp.age, emp.designation);
```

Notice that you can access `age` and `designation` what you are inherited using `prototype`.

Comment: You should extend `Object` otherwise you will get an error, which is pointless because everything extends `Object` anyway.

Comment: Yes! But I just mention here as an example

Comment: @MH2K9  so how could you add a property(Prototype) into a function(Object), could you show me an expmple?

Comment: Yes! Wait i'm writing.

Comment: @slowjams example is added.